# iPhone UIToolbar with UIActionSheet style buttons

Tags: iphone, uibutton, toolbar, uiactionsheet

I have an main window containing a UIToolBarController. In my first tab, I load a UIViewController, where I have an MKMapView. Above the map, I would like a toolbar like on the screenshot below (basically, instead of their UITableView I have an MKMapView...):

[image: Clock app with top UIToolBar and UIActionSheet style buttons]

I'd like to know how I can make this big toolbar on top, and would like to add just une UIActionSheet style button ("Start" in green, and when clicked switch to red "Stop").

Thanks!

PS: The app from the screenshot is Clock if you want to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a toolbar or an action sheet. Your picture shows a UIView with two UILabel objects and two UIButton objects. The UIButton objects have pretty png files as their background images.
The UITableView is simply made not to take the whole screen. In IB a UITableView will normally try to take the whole screen, but you can always resize it.

So, if I was going to try to make this interface in IB I would start with a UIViewController and I would add a UIView (if it wasn't already there). I would resize the UIView to take up half of the screen. Then I would add a UITableView and resize it to take up the other half of the screen. Then I would add the two UILabels and the two UIButtons.
I would wire all of those things to my UIViewController's file. The UIViewController file would have 1 @property that was a UIView, 1 @property that was a UITableView, 2 @properties that were UILabels and 2 @properties that were UIButtons.

Comment: That's why I was thinking, because I can't find anything to create this type of button without using an image that is a copy of a UIActionSheet button. Then I know we can change the height of a UIToolbar by changing the frame, but not really a good effect either. I guess I'll have to find custom images then. If someone has another explanation, I take it too (curiosity). Anyway, thanks @Walter

Comment: There are a number of PSD (photoshop) templates with Action sheet looking buttons you can use. A Google search will turn up lots for you. Also check out the "ButtonMaker" projects on github for some apps you can run in the simulator to make buttons. Just always remember to set the fancy graphics as the background image of your buttons so that you can use the text labels. If you set the button as the main image then you will have to incorporate the text into your image.